# Getting name of file copied to clipboard from email attachment in VB.NET

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, clipboard

If a user copies a file to the clipboard in Windows from an Outlook email attachment, is there any way I can get the name of that file in VB.NET?

If the file is copied from Windows Explorer, `Clipboard.GetFileDropList` has data that I can use to get this, but that list is empty when the file is copied from an email attachment (there are just four available formats - `FileGroupDescriptorW`, `FileGroupDescriptor`, `RenPrivateItem` and `FileContents`).

It feels like this should be possible, since I can paste the file into Windows Explorer and it pastes it with the name of the attachment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that you can get the filename from the data object whose format is `FileGroupDescriptor`. The code is a bit arcane, though:

```
Dim fileName As New StringBuilder("")
Dim theStream As Stream = Clipboard.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor")
Try
    Dim fileGroupDescriptor(512) As Byte
    theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512)

    Dim i As Integer = 76
    While fileGroupDescriptor(i) <> 0
        fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor(i)))
        i += 1
    End While
Finally
    If theStream IsNot Nothing Then theStream.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: [`Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1745023c.aspx) of [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx) will provide you with all available data formats.

Comment: Nice one.
If you need also to extract the attachment to a file go here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/affcf9cd-704d-4ea2-b80b-4c09062af72d